# How to bind an array of DataRows to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

I'd like to partition my search results (which is in a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)) into groups of say 100 so the user navigates through them a chunk at a time.

I thought I could bind an array of DataRows to a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) as the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) but it just does not work. This is the code I tried

```
DataGridView.DataSource = (From r In DataTable.Rows Skip 200 Take 100).ToArray()
```

Can anyone help me out with this? As much as possible, I'd like to stay away using the DataGridView's VirtualMode.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot DataGridView.DataBind()